# Virtual Directory in Azure Web Role

Tags: directory, virtual, azure

Is there a way to create a Virtual Directory in Azure web role.  I know you can create them programmaticly on a normal instance of IIS 7, but you have to assign a physical path.  How is that possible in Azure?

Answer (score 6):

Edit your `.csdef` and add [`VirtualDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557553.aspx#VirtualDirectory) node inside `Site` node

```
<WebRole name="SampleWebApp">
  <Sites>
    <Site name="SampleSite" physicalDirectory="..\SampleWebApp">
      ...
        <VirtualDirectory name="Styles"
                          physicalDirectory="..\SampleWebApp\Styles" />
      </VirtualApplication>
      ...
    </Site>
  </Sites>
  ...
</WebRole>
```

More: [How to Configure the Virtual Directory Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557553.aspx#)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this [Multiple Websites in a Web Role](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Cloud-Cover-Episode-37-Multiple-Websites-in-a-Web-Role)

Answer (score -2):

No.  Web roles on windows azure do not support the concept of a virtual directory.

Comment: similar discussion:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazure/thread/63cbcd88-e143-4b7c-a784-79d1551a222a

Comment: As of 1.3 this was no longer accurate.  You can indeed add a Virtual Directory, through RDP it is easy, but the documentation on doing it programmatically is still lacking...